# Function that returns prime numbers contained between n and 2n - Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: prime-numbers

Write a function `f[n]` that returns prime numbers contained between `n` and `2n`. It's a variation of Chebyshev's inequality. Please, help.

Comment: Do you know about `Prime[]` and `PrimePi[]`?

Comment: Is this a homework problem? If so, it should tagged as such.

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 100;
Select[Prime[Range@@PrimePi[{n,2n}]],#>=n&]
```

returns

```
{101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 100;
Prime[Range @@ ({1 - Boole[PrimeQ[n]], 0} + PrimePi[{n, 2 n}])]
```

> {101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199}

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate